# How to pass kubernetes namespaces dynamically to k8s cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a cronjob that cleans some job since my kubernetes is on older version so cannot use `ttlafterfinished`.  How can I fetch the namespaces that have this job deployed and  pass the namespaces name dynamically instead of repeating the same command several times?

This is my cronjob:

```
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: jobs-cleanup
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: cleanup-operator
          containers:
          - name: jobs-cleanup
            image: google.io/test/job:1.0
            args:
            - -c
            - |
              for i in $(seq 9);do 
              kubectl get jobs --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -n dev$i | grep "job-init" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac | tail -n +2 | xargs -I % kubectl delete jobs % -n dev$i;done
              kubectl get jobs --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -n stg1 | grep "fusionauth-job" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac | tail -n +2 | xargs -I % kubectl delete jobs % -n stg1
              kubectl get jobs --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -n pt1 | grep "fusionauth-job" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac | tail -n +2 | xargs -I % kubectl delete jobs % -n pt1
              kubectl get jobs --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -n sit1 | grep "fusionauth-job" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac | tail -n +2 | xargs -I % kubectl delete jobs % -n sit1
            command:
            - /bin/sh
          restartPolicy: Never
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: secret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more flexible alternative to what you're doing now would be to store the list of job names you want to delete in a list/array.  Then, you can iterate through the list of job names and execute the command.

Below is a simpler (IMO) version of your command that uses the `-o=jsonpath` support instead in `kubectl` to specify a search criteria.

```sh
# The list of jobs you want to delete from any/all namespaces.
jobs_list="job-init fusionauth-job"

for job_name in ${jobs_list}; do
    kubectl get jobs -A --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp \
        -o=jsonpath="{range .items[?(@.metadata.name == '${job_name}')]}{.metadata.namespace} {.metadata.name}{'\n'}{end}" \
          | while read namespace job;do kubectl delete job ${job} -n ${namespace};done;
done
```

> ***The following was added as a result of the comments/conversation below.***

If the job names in your cluster have incrementing suffixes, such as `fusionauth-job-01`, `fusionauth-job-02`, etc, and you want to keep *only* the latest instance of that job in a particular namespace, then you will need to leverage something like `jq` so you can do some regular expression matching.  `kubectl`'s `jsonpath` feature doesn't support regular expressions.

As an example, let's assume your cluster has the jobs shown below.

```
NAMESPACE   NAME
default     fusionauth-job-01
team1       fusionauth-job-01
team1       fusionauth-job-02
team1       job-init-01
team1       job-init-02 
team2       fusionauth-job-01
team2       fusionauth-job-02
team2       fusionauth-job-03
```

Furthermore, the jobs are listed in timestamp order, meaning `fusionauth-job-03` is the newest job (whose name matches `fusionauth-job*`) in namespace `team2`, `job-init-02` is the newest job (whose name matches `job-init*`) in namespace `team1`, `fusionauth-job-02` is the newest job (of that name pattern) in namespace `team1`, and `fusionauth-job-01` is the only job running in namespace `default`.

After running your `jobs-cleanup` job, the expectation is that the following jobs would be left:

```
NAMESPACE   NAME
default     fusionauth-job-01
team1       fusionauth-job-02
team1       job-init-02 
team2       fusionauth-job-03
```

A script to produce these results is shown here:

```sh
# The list of job name prefixes you want to delete from any/all namespaces.
jobs_list="job-init fusionauth-job"

for job_name in ${jobs_list}; do
    ns_observed=""
    echo "Searching for ${job_name}*"
    kubectl get jobs -A --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o json \
        | jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name | test('\"${job_name}\"')) | .metadata.namespace + " " + .metadata.name' \
        | tac \
        | while read namespace job;do
            if test "${ns_observed#*$namespace}" != "$ns_observed";then
                # If we've seen this namespace already for this job, then delete the
                # job, since the one we found previously is the newest.
                kubectl delete job ${job} -n ${namespace};
            else
                # Otherwise, if this is the first time observing this namespace, then
                # this is the newest job that starts with this job name in this namespace.
                ns_observed="$ns_observed $namespace";
            fi;
        done;
done
```

Comment: But I want to preserve the latest job also. In your code, it's not happening

Comment: That's right.  This detail was not part of your original question.  So, I'm "guessing" that you have multiple jobs with similar names in a single namespace, such as "fusionauth-job-1", "fusionauth-job-2", and so on.  And, you want to keep only the most recent job whose name includes "fusionauth-job" in that namespace.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want to keep only the lasest one for each job

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have `jq` available in your `jobs-cleanup` container image?  kubectl's jsonpath doesn't support regular expressions, which is what you would need.  If you have access to `jq`, then the script above could be redone fairly easily.

Comment: yes I have jq installed in the image

Comment: Can you help me with that

Comment: Yep, I'll take a look at it again shortly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was the perfect answer I was looking for